# PHP not loading extension even they exists

Tags: php

My PHP is in the path c:\php on a Windows 2012 server
I added c:\php to the PATH variable.

I added php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll in c:\php\ext directory

I added following lines in c:\php\php.ini file:

```
extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

But the following command gives me warning that it cannot find the module whereas it exists there:

```
php --ini
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows

Loaded Configuration File:         C:\php\php.ini
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: php 5.6 @apokryfos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a Windows problem whereby a DLL is reported as "not existing" if itself requires *another* DLL that is not found. So for example:

```
php_someextusingssl.dll    - the file exists
```

But php_someextusingssl.dll requires ssleay32.dll, and *that* is not found at run time. So the error you get is "Cannot load php_someextusingssl.dll: file not found". The file not being found is not php_someextusingssl.dll, it is ssleay32.dll.

How do you solve this problem: get hold of some utility such as [DEPENDS.EXE](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), and open the misbehaving extension. It should display the extension and all the DLLs on which it depends. **IF** I am right, then one or more will be marked red as "missing". Those are the DLLs you need to make available.

**UPDATE 1**: chances are that the missing files are among those listed on [Microsoft SQL Server Driver page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver).

**UPDATE 2**: I've downloaded a copy of the Microsoft driver. Yours depends on ODBC32.DLL, MSVCP110.DLL and MSVCR110.DLL. The latter two are part of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable for x86, which you can find [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328). The first is part of the ODBC32 driver listed as per Update 1.